# API не выдает один лист

Tags: python, api

```
from __future__ import print_function

import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly']


def get_links_from_spreadsheet(id: str, token_file_name: str) -> list:
    """
    Возвращает список строк из первого столбца электронной таблицы Google с заданным идентификатором.
    Пример ввода с https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WrCzu4p5lFwPljqZ6tMQEJb2vSJQSGjyMsqcYt-yS4M
        get_links_from_spreadsheet('1WrCzu4p5lFwPljqZ6tMQEJb2vSJQSGjyMsqcYt-yS4M', 'token.json')

Returns
    ['https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLPszdKAlKCXUhU3r25SOFgBxwCEr-JHVS', ... and so on]
"""
SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID = id
SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME = 'A1:E'
links = []
creds = None
if os.path.exists(token_file_name):
    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file(token_file_name, SCOPES)
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            'credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)

    with open(token_file_name, 'w') as token:
        token.write(creds.to_json())

try:
    service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

    sheet = service.spreadsheets()
    result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,
                                range=SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME).execute()
    values = result.get('values', [])

    if not values:
        print('No data found.')

    for row in values:
        print(row)

    final_links = []
    for x in links:
        final_links.append(x.pop())

except HttpError as err:
    print(err)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(get_links_from_spreadsheet('1WrCzu4p5lFwPljqZ6tMQEJb2vSJQSGjyMsqcYt-yS4M', 'token.json'))
```

Возвращает списки

```
['https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLPszdKAlKCXUhU3r25SOFgBxwCEr-JHVS']

['https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLH2l6uzC4UEW0s7-KewFLBC1D0l6XRfye']

['https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLFt_AvWsXl0ehjAfLFsp1PGaatzAwo0uK']

['https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLMOpZvQB55bfp6ykOLayLqLrjcpv_Sw3P']

None
```

Возвращает отдельные списки, а необходимо чтобы был 1 список со всеми данными. Можете помочь исправить ошибку? А так же появляется None, как это исправить? Уже всю голову сломал.

Comment: Если дорабатывать ваш код, то нужно убрать вывод в цикле `for row in values: print(row)` и добавить `print(final_links)`. По поводу None - вам нужно вызвать get_links_from_spreadsheet без print, т.к. функция get_links_from_spreadsheet у вас ничего не возвращает через return.

Comment: спасибо, уже пробовал. Выводит только None, без ссылок. Может я что-то ещё пропустил? final_links = []
        for x in links:
            final_links.append(x.pop())
            print(final_links)

Comment: Ну у вас links изначально пустой список, вы туда вообще ничего не добавляете. Странно было бы, если бы там вдруг результаты оказались. Цикл нужно по values делать `for x in values: final_links.append(x.pop())`

Comment: Всё заработало, спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 0):

```
    from __future__ import print_function

import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly']


def get_links_from_spreadsheet(id: str, token_file_name: str) -> list:
    """
    Возвращает список строк из первого столбца электронной таблицы Google с заданным идентификатором.
    Пример ввода с https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WrCzu4p5lFwPljqZ6tMQEJb2vSJQSGjyMsqcYt-yS4M
        get_links_from_spreadsheet('1WrCzu4p5lFwPljqZ6tMQEJb2vSJQSGjyMsqcYt-yS4M', 'token.json')

Returns
    ['https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLPszdKAlKCXUhU3r25SOFgBxwCEr-JHVS', ... and so on]
"""
SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID = id
SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME = 'A1:E'
creds = None
if os.path.exists(token_file_name):
    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file(token_file_name, SCOPES)
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            'credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)

    with open(token_file_name, 'w') as token:
        token.write(creds.to_json())

try:
    service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

    sheet = service.spreadsheets()
    result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,
                                range=SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME).execute()
    values = result.get('values', [])

    if not values:
        print('No data found.')

    for row in values:
        print(row)

    final_links = []
    for x in values:
        final_links.append(x.pop())
    print (final_links)

except HttpError as err:
    print(err)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(get_links_from_spreadsheet('1WrCzu4p5lFwPljqZ6tMQEJb2vSJQSGjyMsqcYt-yS4M', 'token.json'))
```